# Local Url got from UIDocumentPicker does not work after 2 or 3 minutes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two questions and am not able to find out the answers after 5 days searching on google.

1. With the help of `uidocumentpicker` i used to access the files and do select a pdf document. 
   After selecting the pdf with the help of `didpicdocuments` method I got the URL of the pdf and stored it to an array. and showed a row in table view with the name of that pdf. now when the user clicks on that row that pdf is opening with the help of `pdfkit` and that URL stored in that array. till now everything is working fine. NOW THE PROBLEM IS after two or three minutes when I again tap on that row it is not opening that pdf, it only opens a blank `pdfview`.
2. While opening selecting the pdf I only want to select the pdf files, not other files and for this, I have used mobile core services and mentioned the pdf type into the document types of a document picker. but it is not working even after it I am not able to select pdf files also.

THANKS

```
func didSelectDocument(doc: String?) {
    let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String("kUTTypePDF")], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    //importMenu.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    if let url = urls.first {
        urlArray.append(url)
    }
}
```

For opening the pdf

```
let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .white
        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vc.view.frame.width, height: vc.view.frame.height))
        let pdfDocument2 = pdfDocuments[indexPath.row-(imageSelected.count)]
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.autoScales = true

        pdfView.document = pdfDocument2.pdf
        vc.view.addSubview(pdfView)

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Whats the logic behind this? `pdfDocuments[indexPath.row-(imageSelected.count)]` ??

Comment: @Scriptable nothing important just i am using same table view to show pdf array and image array. so this is for getting the index of array by using the indexpath nothing much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save them. The URL is a transient hole in the sandbox. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) for `UIDocumentPickerViewController`

> Don’t save URLs provided by the open and move operations. You can, however, save a bookmark to these URLs. Call the bookmarkData(options:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeTo:) method and pass in the withSecurityScope option, creating a bookmark containing a security-scoped URL.

You need to save a Security Scoped bookmark which is essentially a blob of `Data`

Comment: i have tried this approach but didnt succeed. I only want to access pdf file with a url which i am successfully doing before 2 minute but after 2 minutes pdf doesnt open.

Comment: You are saving the bookmark data and then every time you wish to access the PDF you are turning the bookmark data back into a URL?  You cannot save the original URL

Comment: yes i am storing the bookmark data and than while using i am converting bookmark data into the URL. But same thing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Warren's answer covers the theory. And here is some code:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    guard
        let url = urls.first,
        url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    else {
            return
    }
    defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        print(data)
        //DO SMTH WITH YOUR DATA
    } catch {
            print(error)
    }
}
```